# Complexity: Conditional operator vs if-else

Tags: java, if-statement, time-complexity, conditional-operator

I am working on a simple code algorithm with Java, and I am wondering there may be a difference between `? :` and `if-else` when calculating the time complexity. I think they both have the same time complexity, but I am not sure...

For example:

```
if (number == num) {
    count += 1;
}
else {
    count -= 1;
}
```

and

```
count += (number == num) ? 1 : -1;
```

Really thank you if you can tell me the difference between them :-)

Comment: What makes you think that there would be any difference regarding time complexity? Maybe you have understood something wrong and we can clear the confusion then.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is very related, but talks about actual time, not complexity.

Comment: Note that "time complexity" is something very different than "time it takes". If you create a new operator that first sleeps for one hour and then runs the same if check the "time complexity" will still be constant / O(1).

Comment: @Zabuza I ***highly*** doubt OP actually wanted to know about complexity theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, both constructs are in `Theta(1)`, so **constant time**.

Not talking about their content, obviously. But in your case even the content is in constant time. So both of your snippets run in `Theta(1)` time.